# Timezone difference of 1 hour and 6 seconds between timezones

Tags: javascript, time, gmt

When entering `-5364617481000` into the [this page](https://www.epochconverter.com/), the time difference between **GMT+0** and **GMT+1** is 1 hour and 6 minutes.

I get the same behaviour from javascript.
Whats the cause of this? I would expect 1 hour or maybe half an hour difference.

[image: Reference image]

Comment: Can you share your javascript code?  The site in fact repeats your behavior, but with it I'd call this a math question.  If you include your code then it's at least marginally a coding question.  Though I'd say you have a better chance of getting good feedback at https://math.stackexchange.com, if they don't have an answer for you already.

Comment: You can't trust Unix dates before 1900. https://websiteseochecker.com/blog/what-is-timestamp/

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708622/how-to-represent-dates-before-epoch-as-a-unix-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921589/where-is-the-extra-75-seconds-coming-from) addresses a similar topic, where time was moved forward by 75 seconds in 1847. So times before and after that date don't match up even in the same time zone (I noticed a 6 minute difference when using your link and I'm in GMT which theoretically should have no difference). So there's likely other adjustments between that date and yours that are contributing to the ~6 minute difference. What you should do about that depends on what you're using the date for.

Hope this helps